Could Hardy inequality be generalized?
I'm faced with estimate of something like $\Vert \frac{u}{|x|^s}\Vert_{\dot H^N}, N>\frac{n}{2}>s$. Here $n$ is the dimension of space.
From Hardy inequality I know that I can bound $\Vert \frac{u}{|x|^s}\Vert_{L^2}$ by $\Vert u\Vert_{\dot H^s}$, but this doesn't work for the $H^N$ norm.
I'm blocked by this gap and cannot work it out. I wonder if there is any method to estimate this. Here are my attempts.
$\Vert \frac{u}{|x|^s}\Vert_{\dot H^N}^2\sim\int|\xi|^{2N}(\int \frac{\hat u(\eta)}{|\xi-\eta|^{n-s}}d\eta)^2d\xi\leq\iint |\hat u(\eta)|^2\frac{1}{|\xi-\eta|^{2n-2s}}|\xi|^{2N}d\xi d\eta$.
Then I divide $\mathbb{R_\xi^n}$ into two parts: $|\xi-\eta|$ is small or big. The first part is good, because $2n-2s>n$. However, the second part blows up because $2N-2n+2s>n$.
